# equations arrangment

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}    
    (4.1)~ -3x+6 &= (-3)(x)+(3)(2)&\\
&= 3(-x+2)
\end{flalign*}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{OR}
\end{center}
\begin{flalign*}
(4.2)~ -3x+6 &= (-3)(x)+(3)(2)&\\
&= -3(x-2)
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE I am trying to set equations of `4.1` and `4.2` with OR side by side.
I mean in horizontal manner `4.1   OR  4.2`

Comment: Please see [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) for marking up your code samples. I see that you use `flalign*` but why do you provide equation numbers manually?

Comment: Sorry but it is not equation number in fact it's a alternate solution of problem i.e. 4.1 first solution , 4.2 second solution.

Comment: @snehal: Do you need both of these to be numbered? If so, numbers on the left would seem weird for (4.2)...

Comment: no without numbers.

Comment: @snehal: Why do you write `4.1 OR 4.2` then if you want to have them without numbers? This is confusing the users here willing to help you

Answer (score 4):

You can set everything inside an `align*`, just as long as you add the appropriate number of alignment delimiters `&`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align*}
  -3x+6 &= (-3)(x)+(3)(2) &\textbf{OR} && -3x+6 &= (-3)(x)+(3)(2) \\
        &= 3(-x+2)        &            &&       &= -3(x-2)
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Other `align`-like structures would also work for this.